# Flatsome for Woocommerce: Annul file within INC folder

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am trying to modify a part of code inside: themes / flatsome / inc / shortcodes / ux_products.php

I want to change this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">
```

For this

```
<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" aria-label="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
```

I have the same path and file inside the folder of my child theme but I can't annul the main theme file.

I realized that there is another file that refers to the file I want to cancel: themes / flatsome / inc / init.php:

```
if (is_woocommerce_activated()) {
  require get_template_directory() . '/inc/shortcodes/ux_products.php'; //File to annul
  require get_template_directory() . '/inc/shortcodes/ux_products_list.php';
  require get_template_directory() . '/inc/shortcodes/product_flip.php';
  require get_template_directory() . '/inc/shortcodes/product_categories.php';
  if(get_theme_mod('product_layout') == 'custom') {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/shortcodes/custom-product.php';
  }
}
```

How can I do this without having to modify the main theme (this works but it is not correct).

Answer (score 1):

First you need copy the shortcode you need modify to your child theme.

```
'your_child_theme/inc/shortcodes/ux_products.php'
```

Then you need to modify the child shortcode, function name :

```
function ux_products($atts, $content = null, $tag)
```

to

```
function child_ux_products($atts, $content = null, $tag)
```

Modify what you need:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">
```

to

```
<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" aria-label="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
```

And at the end of your child shortcode file, override all (or only needed) declared shortcodes, with your own function :

```
add_shortcode("ux_products", "ux_products");
```

to

```
add_shortcode("ux_products", "child_ux_products");
```

To override all shortcodes :

```
add_shortcode("ux_bestseller_products", "child_ux_products");
add_shortcode("ux_featured_products", "child_ux_products");
add_shortcode("ux_sale_products", "child_ux_products");
add_shortcode("ux_latest_products", "child_ux_products");
add_shortcode("ux_custom_products", "child_ux_products");
add_shortcode("product_lookbook", "child_ux_products");
add_shortcode("products_pinterest_style", "child_ux_products");
add_shortcode("ux_products", "child_ux_products");
```

Finally in your function.php or '/inc/init.php', you need require overrided shortcodes when wp_loaded :

```
function override_shortcodes(){
  if(is_woocommerce_activated()){
    require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/shortcodes/ux_products.php';
  }
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'override_shortcodes', 10);
```

Comment: Works great to load a custom shortcode in Flatsome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this to your child theme's functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'template_directory', 'search_child_template_directory' );
function search_child_template_directory( $template_dir ) {
    if (is_woocommerce_activated()) {
        return get_theme_file_path();
    }
    return $template_dir;
}
```

Comment: I get the following: "It has a critical error on your website". I am following the same folder path, is this ok? copy -> themes/flatsome/inc/shortcodes/ux_products.php to -> themes/flatsome-child/inc/shortcodes/ux_products.php